# How to make a strong publisher in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

In c#,we normally make publisher like below:

```
public class Publisher
 {
    public event Action NotifySomethingEvent;

    public void RaiseNotifySomethingEvent()
    {
        NotifySomething?.Invoke();
    }
 }
```

while the subscriber has define a method like this:

```
public void HandlerSomething()
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

This subscriber would cause the publisher thread blocking.

Do there anyway to fix this issue?
By the way,the publisher BeginInvoke method will cause the subscriber execute time confuse,so is not in consideration.

the subscriber execute time confuse means:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Publisher publisher = new Publisher();
        SubScriber subscriber = new SubScriber();
        publisher.NotifySomething += subscriber.HandlerSomething;
        publisher.RaiseNotifySomething();
        publisher.RaiseNotifySomething();
        publisher.RaiseNotifySomething();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
public class Publisher
{
    public event Action NotifySomething;

    public void RaiseNotifySomething()
    {
        NotifySomething?.Invoke();
    }
}
public class SubScriber
{
    int d = 0;

    ReaderWriterLock locker = new ReaderWriterLock();

    public void HandlerSomething()
    {
        d += 1;
        Action<int> action = new Action<int>((t) =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.WriteLine(t);
        });
        action.BeginInvoke(d, null, null);
    }
}
```

}

the upper code expect result is : 1 2 3 
but in fact it result is random,like 1,3,2  1,2,3 or 3,2,1

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the subscriber execute time confuse".  Could you try to explain that?

Comment: Is `Task.Run(()=>NotifySomething?.Invoke())` an option?

Comment: Read a little about the `Event Aggregator` pattern (Pub-Sub). There are async implementations for this pattern.

Comment: Or make the handler asynchronous. `public async void HandlerSomething()` and `await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(2000));`

Comment: Make the handler asynchronous also cause the unanticipated result,I'will try 'Event Aggregator',thanks for all suggestion.

Comment: Wait. you do not want the calls to block the thread but do want them to be executed in order? You could build a queue and use a thread to dequeue the  notifications in order when they have been handled (sync).

Comment: @Aphelion Correct,that's what I want,do there any samples about this?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you do not want the subscribers to block the publishing thread but do want them to be executed in published order.

You could enqueue your published events and have another thread dequeue these events in order and wait for the subscribers to finish their job.

Building this can get dirty so I recommend you find a Pub-Sub library you feel comfortable with.

I would recommend the `MassTransit` project. It works async. It has queues. Additionally, you can put the concern of orchestrating the events into a workflow (called a Saga), whicht might come in handy when your project gets more complex.

I am unaware of the complexity of your project. MassTransit supports RabbitMQ but also in-memory as the transport layer. So it scales very well.

Comment: Hello,I have read a little about 'MassTransit',it's normally used in Application Communication(I think it is too heavy for my application while my application is a configure and monitor desktop application ),have you ever try any simple message communication pub-sub library inside the application?

Comment: Yes I did. The library supports a lot of complexity but its not mandatory. You could just use the Bus and in-memory transport which replaces the RabbitMQ dependency. However, I thought it was more important you understand the concept behind it. Therefore you could look for a library that better meets your requirements.

Comment: ActionBlock  in 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll' could perferct match my problem.[link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97199/chaining-asynchronous-tasks-that-must-run-sequentially)

Answer (score 1):

It is already done and is called [ReactiveExtensions](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive).

It implements IObservable interface which can publish events and you can subscribe to them. It also covers end of events and errors. Take a look.

There even is MVVM framework based on them called [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/)

Comment: 'ReactiveExtensions' is great!But it would change a lot,thanks all the way.